# Ubuntu Graphics Card and Installation Problems

Tags: installation

I last tried Ubuntu when it was 7.04 and it had a lot of issues with my old computer.  Good that I managed to fix the Sound Card.

My PC broke after that and I stopped using Ubuntu for a few years.  Then recently I got a new PC and I decided to try Ubuntu 12.04 again since I liked it more than Windows before.

My new PC has 2 internal and 1 external HD.

1. If I put Ubuntu on my external HD (only data on it) will it affect the Windows installation on the Internal HD?
2. I have an ATI Radeon 2100 video card.  Will it work with Ubuntu?

Comment: ok instant vote down for question. am i not giving enough info? people were very helpful before when when i needed help. i thought the question was fairly straightforward

Comment: thanks for the help guys. I'm just downloading the windows installer, it'll either work or it wont (hopefully it does). Fingers xd iv done it right and i dont lose my windows or any of my data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently running 11.10 with no problems. I'm running an nVidia gpu and an AMD Phenom 965 II x 4 cpu. As for dual booting, that's what I do. So, yep... still possible. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by putting ubuntu on the spare internal w/ no os on it... Are you going to wipe the data from that drive? Are you going to use it strictly for Ubuntu?